# Java recursion and Merge Sort

Tags: java, merge, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying to write a simple merge sort program in Java, I'm seeing a lot of red in Eclipse. I'm still a beginner, and don't quite see whats wrong. thanks.

-Kyle

```
public class merge{ 
public static int[] mergeSub(int[] array, int left, int right){
        if(left<right)
        {
        int mid = (left+right)/2;
        int[] a = mergeSub(array, left, mid);
        int [] b = mergeSub(array, mid+1, right);
        return merge(a, b);

}
        int[] arr=new int[1];
        arr[0]=arr[left];
        return arr;
}

static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right){
        int index =0; int indexLeft =0; int indexRight=0;
        int[] result = new int[left.length+right.length];

        while(indexLeft<left.length && indexRight<right.length){
                if(left[indexLeft] <= right[indexRight])
                {
                        result[index]=left[indexLeft];
                        index++;
                        indexLeft++;

                }
                else{
                        result[index]=right[indexRight];
                        index++;
                        indexRight++;
                }
        }

        if (indexLeft<left.length){
                while(indexLeft<left.length){
                        result[index]=left[indexLeft];
                        indexLeft++; index++;
                }
        }
        if (indexRight<right.length){
                while(indexRight<left[indexRight]){
                        result[index]=right[indexRight];
                        indexRight++; right[indexRight]++;
                }
        }
        return result;
}



public static void main(String args[]){

        int[] array = {2, 4, 5, 7, 5, 6, 3, 5, 7, 8};
        System.out.println(mergeSub(array, 0, 9));
}}
```

Comment: It would be easier if you could describe one or two of the more common errors.

Comment: Im not sure, eclipse seems to compile it but having trouble still

Comment: Take the time to properly indent your code. This will make it more readable and understandable as well as expose a wide range of bugs. Eclipse can help you with standard automatic formatting that you can configure until you find your "style". I simply refuse to go over code that is not consistently formatted; this includes when I tutor.

Comment: Update your question to the latest version of your code. If you still have troubles, I can post a working version. I still hope that you will solve it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by making it less red in Eclipse :-)

When you mouse over the error, it tells you what the error is. For example, in your `mergeSub` code you're declaring `left` and `right` as local arrays even though `left` and `right` are already declared as `int` parameters. Name your local variables differently.

Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

My Java's a bit rusty, but I believe that in Java, EVERYthing must be in a class. You don't seem to declare any classes in your code sample, but maybe you just left them out for brevity?

Comment: Ok, made class called merge, also from first answer

Answer (score 0):

First off... your main function mergeSub is declared as a static (which is fine) but you can't call non-static functions. Either make merge static, or make mergeSub a method of the containing class.

Comment: I addes a class merge, should this do it?

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste is your evil. I don't want to show the whole working code, so:

in mergeSub:

```
arr[0]=arr[left]; should be arr[0]=array[left];
```

in merge:

```
while(indexRight < left[indexRight]) should be while(indexRight < right.length)

right[indexRight]++; should be index++;
```

maybe there was more. Oh, and you can not print an array with println() you have to iterate through it.

Comment: You can also print an array using Arrays.toString(array)

Answer (score 0):

I can see one problem (though it doesn't explain the compile-time errors):

`mergeSub()` does not check for being passed an empty array.  If you do pass it an empty array you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at the `arr[0]=array[left];` statemnt

Answer (score 0):

After you've gotten rid of the red, based on the feedback given, you can compare your implementation with this [one](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Mergesort#Java) @ codecodex.com to see how it stacks up and learn some more.