# is it possible to implement any sorting algorithm in place without any loops?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, recursion

I'm looking to implement a sorting algorithm for an array(no matter which) without using any loops(recursively) and in-place(without using any helping arrays).
Please note: I need a strictly no loop AND no helping array code. Does anything like this exists?

I tried to build this method:

```
private static void sort(int [] a, int low, int high,int length)
{
    if(low>length)
        return;
    else if(low<=length)
        {
            if(high<a.length-low-1)
                {
                    if(a[high]>a[high+1])
                        {
                            int temp=a[high];
                            a[high]=a[high+1];
                            a[high+1]=temp;
                        }

                    else
                    {
                    high=0;
                    low++;
                    }

        }   

            sort(a,low,high+1,length);
    }
}
```

called from main with sort(a,0,0,a.length), I keep getting null\infinite recursion. Would appreciate assistance.

Not concerned about complexity.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried any recursive algorithm?

Comment: was a good question until you asked for existing resources.

Comment: tobias- using recursion instead

Comment: Check quick sort recursive implementation(recursion with no helper array): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) applies here.  This question is easily answered with a search engine, either here on SO or on the web overall.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java recursion and Merge Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604869/java-recursion-and-merge-sort)

Comment: Its not really the same question @Prune

Comment: It's just one of many questions pertaining to a recursive sort in Java.  I encourage you to look around and find what you need; you described the main problem well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Without helping arrays I'm not sure, but this is a way to sort without a loop

```
public static Result[] sort(Result[] array)
{
    int lastElement = array.length - markpass;
    int largePos = findLargestMark(array, array.length - markpass);
    if (largePos != array.length - markpass)
    {
        Result temp = array[largePos];
        array[largePos] = array[lastElement];
        array[lastElement] = temp;
    }

    markpass++;

    if (markpass != array.length)
    {
        sort(array);
    }
    else
    {
        return array;
    }

    return array;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! You wrote you are not sure about helping arrays but I don't see any here? Also, what does markpass signify?

Comment: By helping arrays I assume you mean temp arrays? Result temp = array[largePos];  and it's just an integer that increases after each pass so we can determine when we reach the end of the array (an index)